# How to run django-pytest on a project which imports settings from environment variables defined in manage.py

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I'm working on a Django project in which settings such as `SECRET_KEY` are defined in a `.env` file, and `manage.py` sets the environment variable using [python-dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) as follows:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
    # usual manage.py code
```

Then `settings.py` simply defines module-level settings from environment variables, for example,

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

I'm now in the process of switching to [pytest-django](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for unit testing. The problem, however, is that without running `python manage.py` first, the environment variables don't get set, so I end up with

```
E   KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
```

The way I'm now thinking of working around this is to define a custom action to register with `manage.py` to run `pytest` (following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/). This seems a bit like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut, though. Any suggestions of more elegant ways to go about this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach could be to create a test runner for Django as described at https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-use-manage-py-test-with-pytest-django

Answer (score 4):

You could use `os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')`, which will return `None` if there is no such environment variable. That's equivalent to `os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')` and similarly allows an optional second argument for a default value (e.g. `os.getenv('SECRET_KEY', 'my-default-key')`.

This is the approach that most of the projects I've worked on have taken, both for testing and for local development reasons.